# Is there a way to pass a Map() object to different stateful widget in different screens?

Tags: object, flutter, dart, widget, stateful

For example,
I have a simple Map() in main.dart.

And I have 3 screens with different stateful widgets,

screen1.dart => Screen1()

screen2.dart => Screen2()

screen3.dart => Screen3()

## In main.dart

```
var people1 = {

name:”Peter”,
age:20,

}
Main(){
  runApp(screen1(people1));
}
```

=========================

## screen1.dart

(imported main.dart)

```
class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Screen1State createState() => _Screen1State();
}


class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(Text(“${people.age}”);
  }
}
```

I cannot get the people.age in other screens. Even I imported the dart file.
How can I transfer to stateful widget in other screens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make constructor in your Screen1

```
class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {  
  final Map people;

  const Screen1(this.people);
```

and then access it in your statefull class Screen1 like this

```
widget.people.age
```

if your Screen1 would be stateless then you can simply access it by

```
people.age
```

Comment: This is suspicious, I wonder a Map object on dart cannot be accessed by simple attribute.